# Octave containers.map not working inside member function

Tags: containers, octave

I have the following test code which just creates an empty hashmap (containers.map) and fills it up afterwards:

```
 hashtable = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','double');
 hashtable('test') = 1.0;
```

as long as I use it in my "main" file, everything works fine...
But if I copy these 2 lines into a member function of an self created class, there comes the error:

**error: class not found: MyClassName**

**error: called from**

**myMemberFunction at line 15 column 31**

line 15 is the line where "hashtable('test') = 1.0;" stands.
If I remove this one line, everything works fine again.
I absolutly don't understand, why the error sais, it can not find my class...
I tested my class and everything works perfectly.

I set up the class in the following way:

1: created a folder named: "@MyClassName"

2: created a constructor file named: "MyClassName"

3: added a constructor function named: "function obj = MyClassName(obj)"

4: created a member function file named: "myMemberFunction"

5: created a member function within this file: "function obj = myMemberFunction(obj)

If this code (the hashmap) stands within my constructor it works fine.
Only if it stands inside my memberfunction line 15 "hashtable('test') = 1.0;" makes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr - replace

```
hashtable('test') = 1.0;
```

with

```
subsasgn( hashtable, substruct( '()', {'test'} ), 1.0 );
```

---

Not sure if this is intended behaviour, or a side-effect of containers.Map being a classdef defined class, and whether or not this is because old and new style classes don't play well with each other. May be worth submitting a bug for this. But, seems like the problem is because `hashtable('test')` is not parsed as intended inside the method - presumably instead of validly treating it as a 'referencing' operation, it treats it as a function call?

In the interest of completeness, here's an MVCE:

```
% @MyClassName/MyClassName.m
function obj = MyClassName(obj)
    obj = struct('myfield', []);
    obj = class(obj, 'MyClassName');
end
```

```
% @MyClassName/display.m
function display( Obj );
    display( [inputname(1), '.myfield = '] );
    display( get( Obj, 'myfield' ) );
end
```

```
% @MyClassName/get.m
function Out = get( Obj, Field )
    Out = struct(Obj).(Field);
end
```

```
% @MyClassName/set.m
function Obj = set( Obj, Field, Val )
    Obj = struct(Obj);
    Obj.(Field) = Val;
    Obj = class( Obj, 'MyClassName' );
end
```

```
% @MyClassName/myMemberFunction.m
function obj = myMemberFunction(obj)
    hashtable = containers.Map('KeyType', 'char', 'ValueType', 'double');
    subsasgn( hashtable, substruct( '()', {'test'} ), 1.0 );
    obj = set( obj, 'myfield', hashtable );
end
```

In terminal:

```
octave:1> a = MyClassName();
octave:2> a = myMemberFunction(a);
octave:3> a
  a.myfield = 
    containers.Map object with properties:
      Count     : 1
      KeyType   : char
      ValueType : double
```